# How to change IWorkspaceRoot's path in Eclipse Plugin project

Tags: java, path, eclipse-plugin, project

My problem is to open a project from an Eclipse Plugin project 
I have a sample code that works well but My project is not in Workspace. 
It is in a folder which is in WorkspaceRoot path. I have to set a path as "workspaceRootPath/AFolder"  is it possible ?

```
            IProgressMonitor progressMonitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
            IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
            IProject project = root.getProject(pName);
            project.open(progressMonitor);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you created a <workspace>/AFolder through the filesystem?  Is it a project, and you just need to get eclipse to recognize it now?  Or are you saying you have a project at <workspace>/AFolder/theProject?

Comment: I create projects from existing project templates then I copy projects' files to a directory which is in WorkspaceRoot as "<workspace>/projectName/subproject1  - subproject2 etc." 
And then I try to open existing project and add it to package explorer. So just giving path cant effort to add project.
I need a better solution to use workspace root path more flexible.
Temporarily I add whole subprojects in workspace root but when 2 subpoject names are same, It causes problems again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [JavaCore](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/JavaCore.html) class of the jdt.

Just from my memories I think to remember, that the create(IResource resource) method will create a Java project from a given folder.

Does this help?

---

### Edit

To answer the comment question, you could do it like following:

```
IPath path = Path.fromPortableString( "abc/def" );
IWorkspaceRoot workspaceRoot = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot();
IFolder folder = workspaceRoot.getFolder( path );
IResource resource = folder;
```

e.g.

Comment: It really helps me thanks I used :
(IWorkspaceRoot root = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getMember();) 
to get a path inside workspace directory. 
Thanks for your answer.

But there is something else, How can I use any other path as I resource like "/home/abc/def" unreleated from the workspace

Answer (score 2):

OK, the short answer is that what you want is not possible.  The  workspace root will contain `.metadata` and the project folders (that contain the `.project` file).  Eclipse does not support `workspaceRoot/dir/subproj1,subproj2` etc.

The one thing you can do is create your subprojects in separate folders outside the workspace, and then create a project in eclipse that points to the external project.  You do have to give them different names in the workspace, even if they are the same on disk: ex: `pass1/subProj1`, `pass2/subProj1` would have to be named `subProj1` and `subProj1_pass2` in the workspace.

PW

Comment: Ok, if it is not possible, this approach will be useful for me. thanks for your answer.